# Find total no of links to and from node based on data in csv

Tags: excel, csv

I have a csv with the following info

```
Src Rx  LinkId  Weight
===================================
2   1   4000    10
2   1   4056    15
3   1   4100    10
3   1   4156    15
28  1   10650   8
113 2   15051   205
113 3   15058   205
1   4   3952    9
1   4   3951    5
1   4   3950    34
2   4   4052    9
47  4   18672   44
47  4   18670   38
69  4   4701    11
69  4   4700    21
70  4   4801    11
```

`
The linkId is unique. Each row represents the link between two devices. For example, source 2 and rx 1 means that a link goes from 2 to 1.
I intend to compute the total weight of all the links originating from each device and coming into each device like so:

```
Device  Out weight  In weight
=============================
2        25           205
1        48           58

and so on.
```

I would like to know if doing this is possible in excel. If yes, how.

Answer (score 0):

Using a pivot table may be the best solution here and I think that if you select this table and click pivot-table it will give you your answer.

Alternatively, you can make a column for each in and out and use `=sumif(Src, 1, weight )` and then use the totals at the bottom of each column.